# Can I make a batch script uninstaller that deletes itself?

Tags: windows, batch-file, uninstall

I am making some installers for various programs, but would also like to include an uninstaller with them.
I do *not* want to build the installer with NSIS or Inno Setup. I know they do this automatically, but my installers are SFX archive based.
I know how to make the uninstaller delete the specified files I want removed, but is it at all possible to program it to remove itself after everything else from the program is uninstalled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just make it delete itself with `del uninstaller.bat` or `del "%~f0"`, where `%~f0` represents the full path of the script.

Comment: He is talking about SFX, which are executables. But that said, yes it works with executables too. As long as the file does not create a write lock on itself it will work. +1 regardless the tiny mishap.

Comment: That did it, but after converting the script to an EXE it no longer works. Should "%~f0" work if attempting to remove an EXE?

Comment: @Mr.Mendelli What did you use to convert it? It depends on where the script is called. I imagine some converters extract the script into %tmp% and that's what the path might refer to. I tried "Bat to Exe Converter v2.4.3" from F2KO Software, that seems to work.

Comment: I too used Bat to Exe Converter, and named the binary `Test Uninstaller.exe`. I first used your `"%~f0"` with no success on the exe, then I tried `del "Test Uninstaller.exe"`, which was also unsuccessful. I was certain to wrap the file declaration in quotation marks due to it's namespace. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Mr.Mendelli Tried a bunch of different things, both using temp and using the current directory as working directory doesn't affect it. Try making a simple .bat that echoes "%~f0", "%~dpnx0" and "%cd%" (with a pause), convert and start it, then see what those refer to and what the source code contains (which should be in either temp or in the current directory, depending on your settings).

Comment: Its running from the working directory, I would imagine that it would work if thats the case.

Answer (score 1):

[dbenham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1012053/dbenham) found a clever trick to let a batch file delete itself without errors in [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20333575/6811411)

> **cite**
>   In summary, (GOTO) 2>NUL behaves like EXIT /B, except it allows execution of concatenated commands in the context of the caller!
>   
>   So all you need is

```
(goto) 2>nul & del "%~f0"
```

Comment: I tried using this, but this too no longer works once the script is converted to an `exe` format binary. Any suggestions?